# ComboBox to display current month

Tags: datetime, combobox

I want my combobox to display the current month as well as the next two months that follow. This is what I have and I'm not sure in which direction to move:

```
private void comboBoxcMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         DateTime.Now.Month;

    }
```

I receive: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement".

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where do you want it to display? You haven't tried to do so; you've just retrieved the value of the current month and discarded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set 'DateTime.Now.Month' value to your comboBoxcMonth.SelectedValue.
if your comboBoxcMonth contain values like 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

You can  use this in your event.

```
comboBoxcMonth.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.Month;
```

and if you want next two month you can use this instead.

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).Month
```

Comment: I typed this code in and set the values for comboBoxcMonth to 0,1,2,3. When I run the application the dropdown just show 0,1,2,3. I'm obviously missing something but don't know what it is. Do you?

Comment: What is your 'Text' for DropDownList?

DropDownList's item have properties 'Text' and 'Value'.

Comment: Text property was the one that show at scene.
and i wasn't notice at first that you select value in selectedIndexChange event.
Why did you select dropdown value in selectedIndexChangeEvent? This event will be trigger when dropdown was selected to something so if you select it to some index it'll always change to current month.